# Declaring a Object with the name of the class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Card c = deck.deal();
        System.out.println("Got card " + c.getName());
        sum += c.getValue();
    }
```

I don't understand the line `Card c = deck.deal();`.
Card is a different class, deck is an object in the `main()`, `deal()` is in different class.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {

    int Cnumb;
    int Cname;
    String cardName[] = new String[5];
    int cardNum[] = new int[14];


    public void init(){
        cardName[0] = "";
        cardName[1] = "Heart's";
        cardName[2] = "Diamond's";
        cardName[3] = "Spade's";
        cardName[4] = "Club's";

        cardNum[0] = 0;
        cardNum[1] = 1;
        cardNum[2] =2;
        cardNum[3] =3;
        cardNum[4] =4;
        cardNum[5] =5;  
        cardNum[6] =6;
        cardNum[7] =7;
        cardNum[8] =8;
        cardNum[9] =9;
        cardNum[10] =10;
        cardNum[11] =11;
        cardNum[12] =12;
        cardNum[13] =13;

    }

    public void shuffle(){

        Random rnd = new Random();


        // Random Card
        Cnumb = rnd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) % 13;
        Cnumb = Cnumb + 1;

        Cname = rnd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) % 4;
        Cname = Cname + 1;

    }

      public Card deal(){
        String Suit =  cardName[Cname];
        int Rank = cardNum[Cnumb];
        //return ; // here is the problem       
    }

}
```

Comment: You're asking us to guess what code we can't see is doing. Presumably you have the rest of the code available to you. Read it and see what it's doing.

Comment: So there's an error?  You really should have said so in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Card is a class, you're correct. This line of code returns a card object:

```
deck.deal();
```

Deck is another class that encompasses all the cards, and it contains a method called deal that returns a single card.

**Edit:** You have two problems, your method `deal()` is written to return a Card `object`, but you've declared Card as an `array` of `strings`. It's going to cause an error.

Comment: yes sir but i am having an issue with the return type in the deck class..

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the class `Card` is returned by the method in the `Deck` class that is called `deal`. We can't really see exactly what you're asking for, but this is a basic explanation of what's going on.

If you would like some more information on how Object Oriented programming works, here's an excellent tutorial by Brian Will: [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lbXsrHGhBAU).

Comment: maybe this helps i am confused with the return type as it keeps showing the error..

Comment: Oh, it keeps showing an error? What's that error, it should let you know what the return type is.

Comment: it says string cant be converted to card

Comment: Ah, that's simply that the return type of `deck.deal()` is a `String`, not a `Card`. Check the `deal` method inside of your `Deck` class and see where it returns this value. You should then change it to return an array of `Card`s instead of `String`s